# Do linear operators on zero vector always equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm looking at a mathematical induction proof on why the eigenvectors of a linear operator T are linearly independent to each other.

So far I got to the point where for the linear combination of the eigenvectors a1v1 + a2v2 + ... + akvk = 0, we apply (T − λkI) on both sides of the equation to get the following:

a1(λ1 − λk)v1 + · · · + ak−1(λk−1 − λk)vk−1 = 0

What I don't get here is how (T − λkI) on the zero vector on the right side becomes 0. I understand that if you simplify this expression:
(T − λkI)(0)
= T(0) - (λkI)(0)
= T(0) - λk*I(0)
= T(0) - 0
= T(0)

This last part is the problem I'm having. How can you be sure that this linear operator T on zero vector is zero? I believe that I'm missing a very simple concept here, but I just don't seem to grasp it. Can someone help me explain this?

Comment: $T(cv)=cT(v)$. Take $c=0$.

Comment: $T(0)=T(0+0)=T(0)+T(0)$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do all linear transformations map the zero vector to the zero vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106321/do-all-linear-transformations-map-the-zero-vector-to-the-zero-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear operators preserve vector addition and commute with scalar multiplication. You can use either of those facts to show this. Here we use the former:

$L(\vec v+\vec w)=L(\vec v)+L(\vec w)$

Take $\vec v$ to be the zero vector, we get $L(\vec w)=L(\vec 0)+L(\vec w)$

It follows that $L(\vec 0)=\vec 0$